# What's the difficulty class for the paladin's Channel Divinity: Nature's Wrath?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, paladin, difficulty-class

The Oath of the Ancients paladin has the Channel Divinity option Nature's Wrath.

**What's the difficulty class for the Channel Divinity ability?**

All that I've been able to find is that the target makes a Strength or Dexterity saving throw. I have no idea how difficult it is to save, and for the life of me I can't find what the DC is in the book or on the internet.

Comment: Which game is this about? I'm guessing some version of Dungeons & Dragons, but which one?

Comment: D&D 5th edition

Comment: Thanks. I've added a system tag for you. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 19):

The DC for Channel Divinity abilities is described in the main description for your Sacred Oaths, in your list of class features. Specifically, it's:

> Some Channel Divinity effects require saving throws. When you use such an effect from this class, the DC equals your paladin spell save DC.

You can find this (and some other general information about how your Sacred Oath works) on page 85, on the left hand side.

Answer (score 7):

The Channel Divinity element of the Paladin's [Sacred Oath class feature](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/paladin#SacredOath) (Player's Handbook p.85) says:

> Some Channel Divinity effects require saving throws. When you use such an effect from this class, the DC equals your paladin spell save DC.

The Paladin Spellcasting class feature specifies what that DC is:

> ...you use your Charisma modifier when setting the saving throw DC for a paladin spell you cast and when making an attack roll with one.
>
> **Spell save DC** = 8 + your proficiency bonus + your Charisma modifier

In general, if your class has a Spellcasting class feature, the spell attack and save DC listed there will be the right ones to use for any magical class features. It's certainly possible there are examples where that isn't the right choice, but it's a good first guess if you aren't sure.